# How to show a route between two Latlongs in google map in latest android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing a simple map app, where I have to show the path between two geo points. How to show a route between two Latlongs in google map in latest android studio ?  I have made few searches around, most of the solutions have HTTPClient requests which donot seem to work well.

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 0;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String TAG = "MAPTAG";
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng grafi = new LatLng(27.7027937, 85.283888);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(grafi).title("This is Grafioffshore"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(grafi));
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        float zoomLevel = 16;

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can refer this tutorial as it matches your requirements I guess:http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). It has the information you need to show the route between two coordinates.

Hopefully these are all you need for you to start developing your app.